# TensorBoard Starting but not showing in Browser

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Run the code in cells 19 & 23 below to import and pre-process the data.

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/09_up_and_running_with_tensorflow.ipynb

Then lines 59-64 are run to solve a linear least squares problem, whilst saving the training data for use with tensorboard.

I then use Anaconda prompt to do to the directory where the log files are kept:

I then use Anaconda prompt to run:  tensorboard --logdir=\tf_logs

It gives the message
Starting TensorBoard b'54' at http://NW1:6006

But when I try to paste that address into a browser it doesn't work?

I've tried various combinations of absolute path names etc, but nothing seems to work. I've also tried specifying the host as 127.0.0.1

tensorboard --logdir=\tf_logs --host=127.0.0.1

But nothing seems to work!
The webpage is completely blank.

I'm running windows 8.1
Internet Explorer 11
Anaconda 3
Python3.5
Tensorflow 1.1

Everything was installed fresh today so should be up to date

Answer (score 12):

I have faced same issue recently and got it resolved by using following command in command prompt for starting tensorboard

```
tensorboard --logdir=ENTERLOGFOLDERPATH --host localhost --port 8088
```

then open  http://localhost:8088 in your browser

If its not working try changing the port number to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow needs to be started from the same path as the log.

```
C:>tensorboard --logdir=E:\tmp\tensorflow\mnist\logs
```

Tensorflow would start but would not detect the logs.

```
E:>tensorboard --logdir=E:\tmp\tensorflow\mnist\logs
```

Tensorflow would start perfectly.

Please make sure that you are launching tensorboard from the log path.

Secondly, you could try launching it as : 127.0.0.1:6006 in the browser.

Comment: Sorry but these did not work. It must be a fairly subtle bug though as I can get it to work on a windows 7 machine (with Chrome), and as far as I can tell I'm doing the same thing in both instances.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the port to 8080 and host name to 127.0.0.1 and it worked for me

```py
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\logs --port 8080 --host 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue with:

including `--host 127.0.0.1` and pasting the resulting URL *not* into Windows Explorer, but into Google Chrome.

Looks like Windows Explorer is facing some issues here, so try Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Tried simply running it without stating the local host and could not bring up Tensorboard, but then I inserted and stated the localhost:

```
(base) C:\Users\esaeri-1122>tensorboard --logdir=C:\Users\esaeri-1122\Downloads\MLProjects\tensorboard_mnist_digit_logs --host localhost --port 6006
```

TensorBoard 1.13.1 at http://localhost:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Then worked like a charm.